# Trying to export from Capcut to external harddrive get error 'no access to save path'

Tags: video-editor

I've googled this and can't find anyone having the same issue.

Using Capcut on a Mac, trying to export to an external hard drive.

Is there a permissions things I need to grant Capcut?